# Python & HTTPX: How does httpx client's connection pooling work?

Tags: python, http, session, tcp, httpx

Consider this function that makes a simple GET request to an API endpoint:

```py
import httpx 

def check_status_without_session(url : str) -> int:
    response = httpx.get(url)
    return response.status_code
```

Running this function will open a new TCP connection every time the function `check_status_without_session` is called. Now, [this](https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/#more-efficient-usage-of-network-resources) section of HTTPX documentation recommends using the `Client` API while making multiple requests to the same URL. The following function does that:

```py
import httpx

def check_status_with_session(url: str) -> int:
    with httpx.Client() as client:
        response = client.get(url)
        return response.status_code
```

According to the docs using `Client` will ensure that:

> ... a Client instance uses HTTP connection pooling. This means that when you make several requests to the same host, the Client will reuse the underlying TCP connection, instead of recreating one for every single request.

My question is, in the second case, I have wrapped the `Client` context manager in a function. If I call `check_status_with_session` multiple times with the same URL, wouldn't that just create a new pool of connections each time the function is called? This implies it's not actually reusing the connections. As the function stack gets destroyed after the execution of the function, the `Client` object should be destroyed as well, right? **Is there any advantage in doing it like this or is there a better way?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any advantage in doing it like this or is there a better way?

No, there is no advantage using `httpx.Client` in the way you've shown. In fact the `httpx.<method>` API, e.g. `httpx.get`, does [exactly the same thing](https://github.com/encode/httpx/blob/4f8068a7ade1f4d10403e325ed2354109df1724f/httpx/_api.py#L92-L100)!

The "pool" is a feature of the transport manager held by `Client`, which is [`HTTPTransport`](https://github.com/encode/httpx/blob/4f8068a7ade1f4d10403e325ed2354109df1724f/httpx/_transports/default.py#L112) by default. The transport is created at `Client` initialization time and [stored as the instance property `self._transport`](https://github.com/encode/httpx/blob/4f8068a7ade1f4d10403e325ed2354109df1724f/httpx/_client.py#L660).

Creating a new `Client` instance means a new `HTTPTransport` instance, and transport instances have their own TCP connection pool. By creating a new `Client` instance each time and using it only once, you get no benefit over using e.g. `httpx.get` directly.

And that might be OK! Connection pooling is an optimization over creating a new TCP connection for each request. Your application may not need that optimization, it may be performant enough already for your needs.

If you are making many requests to the same endpoint in a tight loop, iterating within the context of the loop *may* give you some throughput gains, e.g.

```py
with httpx.Client(base_url="https://example.com") as client:
    results = [client.get(f"/api/resource/{idx}") for idx in range(100)]
```

For such I/O-heavy workloads you may do even better by executing results in parallel, e.g. using `httpx.AsyncClient`.